# Sed - Capitalize First character of a string ended in a dot

Tags: sed

I need to capitalize (no matter what size of the string (4, 3, 2 or 1)) strings ended in a dot. But, the strings that do not end in a dot bust be kept in lowercase.

These 3 commands were capable of doing what i needed, but in 1-char strings ended in dot, and 2-char strings ended in dot.

```
sed -i -e "/<b>/ {s/\.\([^ ]\)/. \1/g}" file
sed -i -e "/<b>/ {s/\( [a-z]\.\)/\U\1/g}" file
sed -i -e "/<b>/ {s/\([a-z][^ ]\.\)/\u&/g}" file
```

following my stream, i tought that doing this (below), would make pretty much sense, but it did \not\ worked, and made the 3-char strings look like this: `YEs.` and the 4-char strings like `HAHa.`

```
sed -i -e "/<b>/ {s/\([a-z][^ ][^ ]\.\)/\u&/g}" file
```

Can someone help? :p (if possible, point me what have i done wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
sed '/<b>/{s/[a-z]*\./\u&/}' input
```

In your case, `[a-z][^ ][^ ]\.` only matches 3 letters or more. Instead of forcing the existence of `[^ ]`'s you can use `*` to make them optional: `[a-z][^ ]*`

Comment: Shame on me, how could i don't think in this! Thank you @perreal